# finding the long listing of all files that have access time 5 or more days

Tags: linux, find, ls

I want the ls -l output of files that have access time of 5 or more days.

I tried these:

`ls -l | find ~ -atime +5` (only gives result of 'find ~ -atime +5')

`find ~ -atime +1 | ls -l` (only gives result of 'ls -l')

How do I combine these two commands?

Answer (score 0):

Try `find ~ -type f -atime +5 -exec ls -la {} \;`.